# Calender: Show dates upto next 1 week from current week

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello friends I have a calendar with next previous button when user clicks on next button next week schedule will come if again user clicks nothing will happen I want to show dates upto next 1 week

[image]

My JavaScript for Next Button

```
function Next()
    {

    /*sunday*/
    var next_sunday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+7));
    var sunday = [next_sunday.getDate()];
    var smonth = [next_sunday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var syear = [next_sunday.getFullYear()];
    var sunday_date= syear + '-' + smonth + '-' + sunday;
    alert(sunday_date);
    document.getElementById("sunday").innerHTML =sunday;
    /*monday*/
    var next_monday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+1));
    var monday = [next_monday.getDate()];
    var mmonth = [next_monday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var myear = [next_monday.getFullYear()];
    var monday_date= myear + '-' + mmonth + '-' + monday;
    alert(monday_date);
    document.getElementById("monday").innerHTML =monday;

    /*Tuesday*/
    var next_tuesday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+2));
    var tuesday = [next_tuesday.getDate()];
    var tmonth = [next_tuesday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var tyear = [next_tuesday.getFullYear()];
    var tuesday_date= tyear + '-' + tmonth + '-' + tuesday;
    alert(tuesday_date);
    document.getElementById("tuesday").innerHTML =tuesday;
    /*Wednesday*/
    var next_wedday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+3));
    var wednesday = [next_wedday.getDate()];
    var wmonth = [next_wedday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var wyear = [next_wedday.getFullYear()];
    var wednesday_date= wyear + '-' + wmonth + '-' + wednesday;
    alert(wednesday_date);
    document.getElementById("wednesday").innerHTML =wednesday;
    /*Thursday*/
    var next_thuday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+4)); 
    var thursday = [next_thuday.getDate()];
    var thmonth = [next_thuday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var thyear = [next_thuday.getFullYear()];
    var thursday_date= thyear + '-' + thmonth + '-' + thursday;
    alert(thursday_date);
    document.getElementById("thursday").innerHTML =thursday;
    /*friday*/
    var next_friday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+5));
    var friday = [next_friday.getDate()];
    var fmonth = [next_friday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var fyear = [next_friday.getFullYear()];
    var friday_date= fyear + '-' + fmonth + '-' + friday;
    alert(friday_date);
    document.getElementById("friday").innerHTML =friday;
    /*saturday*/
    var next_satday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+6));
    var saturday = [next_satday.getDate()];
    var samonth = [next_satday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var sayear = [next_satday.getFullYear()];
    var saturday_date= sayear + '-' + samonth + '-' + saturday;
    document.getElementById("saturday").innerHTML =saturday;
    alert(saturday_date);
    $("#date").datepicker("setDate", new Date(next_monday));

    var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
    var week_month = months[next_satday.getMonth()] ;
    var week_year = [next_satday.getFullYear()];
    document.getElementById("endDate").innerHTML =week_month +' '+ saturday + ',' + ' ' + week_year;

    }
```

please suggest somthing

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer I used if else loop first I have captured current week last date mean Saturday date and then compared with next saturday

Javascript

```
 function Next()
{
    // get current week saturday
    var textbox_value=document.getElementById("date").value;
    var current_week = new Date(textbox_value);
    var next_satday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+6));
    var current_satday = [next_satday.getDate()];
    //alert(current_satday); 

     // last week saturday as per my requirement 
     // you can modify as per your requirement 
    var curr = new Date;
    var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()));
    var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()+6));
    var last_satday = [lastday.getDate()];
    //alert(last_satday); 

    if(current_satday <= last_satday){ 
    //alert('success'); 

    /*sunday*/
    var next_sunday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+7));
    var sunday = [next_sunday.getDate()];
    var smonth = [next_sunday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var syear = [next_sunday.getFullYear()];
    var sunday_date= syear + '-' + smonth + '-' + sunday;
    //alert(sunday_date);
    document.getElementById("sunday").innerHTML =sunday;
    /*monday*/
    var next_monday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+1));
    var monday = [next_monday.getDate()];
    var mmonth = [next_monday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var myear = [next_monday.getFullYear()];
    var monday_date= myear + '-' + mmonth + '-' + monday;
    //alert(monday_date);
    document.getElementById("monday").innerHTML =monday;

    /*Tuesday*/
    var next_tuesday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+2));
    var tuesday = [next_tuesday.getDate()];
    var tmonth = [next_tuesday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var tyear = [next_tuesday.getFullYear()];
    var tuesday_date= tyear + '-' + tmonth + '-' + tuesday;
    //alert(tuesday_date);
    document.getElementById("tuesday").innerHTML =tuesday;
    /*Wednesday*/
    var next_wedday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+3));
    var wednesday = [next_wedday.getDate()];
    var wmonth = [next_wedday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var wyear = [next_wedday.getFullYear()];
    var wednesday_date= wyear + '-' + wmonth + '-' + wednesday;
    //alert(wednesday_date);
    document.getElementById("wednesday").innerHTML =wednesday;
    /*Thursday*/
    var next_thuday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+4)); 
    var thursday = [next_thuday.getDate()];
    var thmonth = [next_thuday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var thyear = [next_thuday.getFullYear()];
    var thursday_date= thyear + '-' + thmonth + '-' + thursday;
    //alert(thursday_date);
    document.getElementById("thursday").innerHTML =thursday;
    /*friday*/
    var next_friday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+5));
    var friday = [next_friday.getDate()];
    var fmonth = [next_friday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var fyear = [next_friday.getFullYear()];
    var friday_date= fyear + '-' + fmonth + '-' + friday;
    //alert(friday_date);
    document.getElementById("friday").innerHTML =friday;
    /*saturday*/
    var next_satday = new Date(current_week.setDate(current_week.getDate() - current_week.getDay()+6));
    var saturday = [next_satday.getDate()];
    var samonth = [next_satday.getMonth() + 1] ;
    var sayear = [next_satday.getFullYear()];
    var saturday_date= sayear + '-' + samonth + '-' + saturday;
    document.getElementById("saturday").innerHTML =saturday;
    //alert(saturday_date);
    $("#date").datepicker("setDate", new Date(next_monday));

    var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
    var week_month = months[next_satday.getMonth()] ;
    var week_year = [next_satday.getFullYear()];
    document.getElementById("endDate").innerHTML =week_month +' '+ saturday + ',' + ' ' + week_year;
    }
```